# Build a dataframe of nested tibbles in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, functional-programming, dplyr, tibble

I have a couple of tibbles:

1:

```
structure(list(contacts = c(151, 2243, 4122, 6833, 76, 123)), .Names = "contacts", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

2:

```
structure(list(image_names = c("/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/1.png", 
"/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/10.png", "/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/2.png", 
"/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/3.png", "/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/4.png", 
"/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/5.png")), .Names = "image_names", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

3:

```
structure(list(phone_number = c(22881, 74049, 74049, 22881, 22881, 
22881), isInContact = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE), 
    callDuration = c(1, 0, 0, 71, 13, 54), Date = structure(c(17689, 
    17689, 17689, 17690, 17690, 17690), class = "Date"), Time = structure(c(76180, 
    77415, 84620, 27900, 28132, 29396), class = c("hms", "difftime"
    ), units = "secs")), .Names = c("phone_number", "isInContact", 
"callDuration", "Date", "Time"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

And consider that for each set of these dataframes I can get an identifier, say UUID.

I want to build a large dataframe object where the identifier will be user's uuid and all other columns will be nested tibbles:

```
UUID contacts images    call_logs
123  <tibble> <tibble>  <tibble>
456  <tibble> <tibble>  <tibble>
```

Please advise how can I build such thing, I am trying to use `map_dfr` without luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could place the tibbles in a `list` to create a single row

```
tblN <- tibble(contacts = list(tbl1), images = list(tbl2), 
               call_logs = list(tbl3))
```

It is not clear whether the same dataset should be replicated or not for different 'UUID's.

```
list(`123` = tblN, `456` = tblN) %>%
                bind_rows(.id = 'UUID')
```

Comment: Each row has it's own uuid - it's one row per user with all his device data.

Comment: @steves thanks, but how do you get the each of the datasets for each row.  Is it coming from a loop?

Comment: I have tons of files, each of them is a JSON file.
I am just taking all of them and extract for each user it's UUID and you solved my issue as always! Now I get a row per user with all user device data as columns of lists of tibbles.

Comment: I am thinking that we could automate the extraction process

Comment: How? Please share your idea.

Comment: @steves  If you have lots of JSON files, may be loop through the files with `map`, do the extraction and conversion within the loop, set the names of the `list` elements with `UUID` and bind the rows as showed here